# How to delete an object in nested array of objects in MongoDB with node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nested, http-delete

I'm still a beginner in node express js and mongoDB. Right now, I'm trying to Delete an object in nested array of objects.

**Array of Objects:**

```
[{
  _id: new ObjectId("63d89f8823981819cf61816e"),
  iqc: [
    {
      partname: 'jio',
      vendorname: 'jio',
      partcode: '1234',
      grndate: '2023-01-10',
      project: 'jio',
      lotqty: '200',
      failurerate: '15%',
      issuedetails: 'damaged',
      status: 'pending',
      _id: new ObjectId("63d89f8823981819cf61816f")
    },
    {
      partname: 'sky',
      vendorname: 'sky',
      partcode: '5678',
      grndate: '2023-01-04',
      project: 'sky',
      lotqty: '300',
      failurerate: '20%',
      issuedetails: 'damaged',
      status: 'pending',
      _id: new ObjectId("63d89f8823981819cf618170")
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}]
```

I want to delete the object in iqc  which has the **_id: new ObjectId("63d89f8823981819cf618170")**.

So i tried this code for deleting in node js. It didnt work.It throws an error data.iqc.findByIdandDelete is not a function

```
app.delete('/delete/:id/:secondid', async (req, res) => {
    const data = await IQC.findById(req.params.id);

if(data )
    {
        await data.iqc.findByIdandDelete(req.params.secondid)
        return res.json("Deleted  Successfully")
    }

});
```

Here IQC is the db collection and secondid is the id of the nested object id which I wanted to delete **_id: new ObjectId("63d89f8823981819cf618170")**.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This should be working in NodeJS. No problemo.

```
app.delete('/delete/:id/:secondid', async (req, res) => {
  await IQC.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      _id: req.params.id
    }, {
      $pull: {
        iqc: {
          _id: req.params.secondid
        }
      }
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delete but update using [$pull](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) because you are updating the array (removing the object).

So you can try something like this

```js
yourModel.update({
  "iqc._id": req.params.id
},
{
  "$pull": {
    "iqc": {
      "_id": req.params.id
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cJtN1uLIdeu)